Customizing fonts on title page of R Quarto pdf report
I'm using extension 'titlepages' for Quarto to generate a PDF report and need to customize some text on the cover page by assigning custom font size and style. Link to this extension: https://nmfs-opensci.github.io/quarto_titlepages/04-coverpages.html
The texts that need customizing is in the 'elements' block "Some Text .. needs customizing" in reproducible code below:
---
title: "This is the Title"
subtitle: "This is the subtitle" 
author: 
  - "Name1"
  - "Name2"
include-in-header:
  text: |
   \usepackage{authblk}
date: today 
engine: knitr
editor: visual
format: 
  titlepage-pdf:
    titlepage: formal 
    titlepage-logo: 
    titlepage-header: "THE AUTHORS"
    titlepage-footer:  |
       - Footer 1 <br>
       - Footer 2
    titlepage-theme:
      elements: ["\\logoblock","\\titleblock", "\\vspace{1.5cm}", "Some Text 1 needs customizing", "\\vspace{1.5cm}", "\\authorblock",  "\\dateblock", "Some Text 2 needs customizing", "\\vspace{1.5cm}", "\\headerblock", "\\footerblock"]
mainfont: Calibri
monofont: Calibri
include-before-body: 
      text: |
        \pagenumbering{roman}
---

